# How to hide which have calc css?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to hide the element which have calc css3:

```
nav{width: calc(100% - 20px); height: 50%;}
```

I tried this:

```
 $('*').filter(function() {
     return $(this).css('width') == 'calc';
 }).css("display","none");
```

But seems wrong way to do?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7DrVE/)

Comment: Refer following link it may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820559/hide-image-of-specific-size-by-css

Comment: `css` returns the _computed_ styles, you should read and filter the CSS rules which is _very expensive_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`css` method returns the *computed* value of the properties, you should read and filter the initial CSS rules:

```
var s = document.styleSheets[1], // the second stylesheet (for jsfiddle)
    rules = s.cssRules,
    selector = [],
    l = rules.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    if ( rules[i].style['width'].indexOf('calc') > -1 ) {
        selector.push( rules[i].selectorText );
    }
}

$( selector.join() ).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/webozine/9EZ3k/

Comment: does it work even if the browser doesn't support calc because which is not supported that remove the style from them?

Comment: @C-link No, since `calc` is an unknown(_or invalid_) value for them, those browsers should set the value to an empty string.

Comment: if so can i use an empty string? no- this is not good way. So any idea?

Comment: @C-link Well, the only option is reading the stylesheet's body, probably using regex.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't support a filter with the `calc()` function in CSS. Following is the screenshot of me testing zooming in and see the css property changing of the `nav` object.

[image]

Here's a somewhat ugly hack I've come up with, it does filter your requirement though.

```
$('*').filter(function() {
     return  $(this).css('width') == $(this).parent().width()-150 + "px";;
 }).css("display","none");
```

Or, indeed, add a css class and problem solved..

Comment: FYI: See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/7DrVE/15/ this is not filter but background which won't work?

Comment: Yeah you're right, sorry. The updated js function would filter a css class with property of "width:calc(100% - 150px)", please check that

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery you can also try by **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7DrVE/17/)**

```
$('*').filter(function() {
          return $(this).css('width').indexOf('calc');
 }).css("display","none");
```