# How to hide an image by src attribute in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I’m trying to find an image that has a src that starts with a particular url and hide it. I can do it but it doesn’t work on IE.

Is there a version of this css (maybe javascript) that will also work for edge and IE

```
img[src ^= "https://www.google"]{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The selector seems fine. Might have to do with the space before and after `^=`

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS3 [attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings):

```
img[src*="hideme"] {
        display: none;
    }
```

As usual, some versions of IE are known to have bugs with CSS3 attribute selectors. The SitePoint Reference is useful: [Link](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-selectors-attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example tested with IE 11 and MS Edge browser version 44. In both and other browsers the code is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img[src*="i.postimg.cc"] {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/13D5v67n/223.png" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">

</body>
</html>
```

Reference:

[Hide image of specific size, by CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820559/hide-image-of-specific-size-by-css) (Refer the accepted answer in the thread.)