# How to define (style-)width in a separate .css file?

Tags: css, html

**Edited after seeing a few copy& paste errors**

Until I read the question [HTML5 - Can I use Width and Height in IMG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784868/html5-can-i-use-width-and-height-in-img) I thought that there is only 1 way of defining the width/height of elements. 1 way in the
sense of that it always works the same.

Now that question has intrigued me and I began to wonder. With separate .css files I only know of 1 way to define height/width for elements:

```
img#myexample { width: 48px; height: 48px }
```

Now in the linked question there were 2 different ways of how the width were defined (*corrected the error there in the original question where px were mentioned in the first varian*t):

```
<img src="...(here image)...." width="50" height="50" />
<img src="...(here image)..." style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
```

I did not know until that question that both of these have different results. So my question is how
would I need to adapt the above .css line to include both variants (or is that possible / adviceable at all)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, they may be **written** differently but the fundamental effect is the same. There aren't **different** width settings when comparing inline css to css in a stylesheet.

Comment: that is what I had also thought at least until the referenced questions-answer. There it is stated that both are a bit differently interpreted by the browser

Comment: Please read a basic introduction to CSS. That will cover how to apply rules to an element from a stylesheet (instead of inline with a style attribute) if [the example in the question you link to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15347036/19068) is insufficient.

Comment: I updated the question so that I hope it becomes clearer. The width/height I know how to do in a separate .css file BUT the style width/height (as they are seemingly handled differently I'm not sure how to address those tehre)

Comment: They are not handled differently. You've just introduced a couple of syntax errors. See the example in the answer to the question you linked to.

Comment: In CSS you have to use ':' instead of '=' => `img{width:50px;}`

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that if you do it like that, ALL img will be 50px in width by default so you might want to define a class if you want to apply it on several images, or if you just need that for one image do it inline.

Comment: Clenaed up the question (should have taken a bit more time to look before I copy & paste even if from another question). Also tried to clarify what I'm looking for a bit more as the answers so far indicate that I didn't clarify it enough.

Answer (score 0):

To be add to use an external css stylesheet you have link it in the head of your HTML page.

***HTML***

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 //Link to your stylesheet below
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourstylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Blah Blah</h1>
  <img src="your image source" alt="Some text"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Now that you have external stylesheet linked in your HTML now you can  modify the elements in the body of your HTML page.

***yourstylesheet.css***

```
h1{
 font-size: 14px;
}
img{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The stylesheet will overwrite what you define in the attributes.
So if you define `img{width:100px;}` in a stylesheet and use an img tag like `<img src="pic.png" width="200px" />`, the image will be 100 pixels wide. If you do not define a width in your stylesheet, the attribute will be used of course.

You can define the css either in your html document like with surrounding  tags or have a .css-file that you link like this (which is usually cleaner in a large project).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: "The attributes will overwrite what you define in a stylesheet." — Incorrect. The CSS specification requires that CSS takes priority over presentational HTML attributes.

Comment: kevin I just updated the qustion to be a bit more clear (I'm not sure how to do the "style" variant as from the referenced question it sounded like those two are interpreted differently and I'm not sure how BOTH can be given in a separate .css file.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, seems I had that wrong in my head. I updated my answer accordingly.