# Unset width to revert back to inline html attribute "width=XX"

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make an image size to whatever the attribute says `(width=XX)` and not the CSS. That's what the Wordpress Html editor sets when you use the UI drag corner to resize the image to 85 x 30. However, the theme has some css `height/width:auto` which makes the `img` go to it's natural dimensions and I can't find a way to 'kill' that CSS so it reverts to the inline one. (Without editing the theme CSS of course)

I tried with `width:unset` and `inherit` to no avail. Any ideas?

```css
/* Untouchable CSS */
.row .col img:not([srcset]) {
    width: auto;
}

.row .col img {
    height: auto;
}
/*End Untouchable CSS */

img{
  width:unset  !important; /*doesn't work*/
  height:unset  !important; /*doesn't work*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#"><img width="85" height="30" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo"></a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting problem! I thought that `auto` ___was___ the default value of the `width` and `height` attribute! Now I posted a workaround below, but I'll gladly yield to someone who has the real answer.

Comment: @MrLister `auto` is the default value but the image is bigger than the value specified in the attribute of the image, so by specyfing auto on both height and width you erase these values and the default size is considered ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif If `auto` is the default, then how do you explain what happens in the OP's code? In the absence of any styles, `<img width="80" src="...">` is 80 pixels wide. But if you then add `img {width: auto}` to the stylesheet, the width becomes the width of the source graphic! See fiddles, [before](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hpypay2f) and [after](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hpypay2f/1/)

Comment: @MrLister if you add `width:auto` and `height:auto` both of them will erase the value in the images (both of them need to be present) an *auto* mean the default width of the image (*Default value. The browser calculates the width*)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Adding `height: auto` as well makes no difference to my fiddles. I still don't know what happens. You also posted as your answer only a workaround, without really solving the question of what exactly is going on.

Comment: @MrLister what is happening is that the height or width is being erased (check dev tool) .. width:auto = the width of the image calculated by the browser (it's overriding the width specified). And my answer is not a workaround, i simply removed one of the auto value so the specified value is then considerd. Am gonna add more explantion to my answer thought ;)

Comment: @MrLister i added more explanation to my answer, hope it's clear now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the attribute `srcset=""` to the image to avoid the first style being applyed and remove the style you added. The idea is to keep only one CSS property to `auto` (height or width) and the other one will get the value specified on the image and your image will have the desired height/width:

*By the way I advice you to specify a correct value to `srcset` and don't leave it empty*

```css
/* Untouchable CSS */
.row .col img:not([srcset]) {
    width: auto;
}

.row .col img {
    height: auto;
}
/*End Untouchable CSS */
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#"><img width="85" height="30" srcset="" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo"></a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To add more clarifation, specifying `width:auto` and `height:auto` override the value specified in the attribute of the image.

[image]

And the `auto` value means *The browser will calculate and select a width for the specified element.* and then the image will get it's original/default size.

By removing one of the `auto` value (in this case for the width), the value of the image attribute will be considered again and the other one, since it's always auto, will be calculated by the browser and in this case it **will fit** the value in the attribute becasue the browser will keep the ratio while calculating, but you can specify any value you want it won't be considered.

Here is a code to show this:

```css
.col img {
  height: auto;
}

.col2 img {
  height: 100px;
}

.col3 img {
  height: 300px; /* 300px will overribe the value in the attribute */
  width:auto; /* auto will override the attribute so the browser will calculate the width by keeping the ratio of the image*/
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img width="85" height="30" srcset="" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo">
</div>

<div class="col">
  <!-- specify a big height value here  -->
  <img width="85" height="300000" srcset="" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo">
</div>
<div class="col2">
  <!-- for this one the width is specified in attribute and height in CSS  -->
  <img width="85" height="300000" srcset="" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo">
</div>
<div class="col3">
  <img width="85" height="300000" srcset="" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo">
</div>
```

Here is a similar question with more details :

[HTML5 - Can I use Width and Height in IMG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784868/html5-can-i-use-width-and-height-in-img)

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: OK, nice. It still doesn't answer the OP's question, what would be the CSS to write if you want to revert the sizes to the default, if it's not `auto`.

Comment: @MrLister i guess you cannot as these attribute doesn't belong to CSS and simply help the browser to decide about the width/height of the element so whenever you specify any value to width/height in the CSS they will no longer be considered at all. And whataver you will do in the CSS there will be always a styling in the CSS that will override them and make them non considered.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand now. The default value, `auto` will be used if there are no other influences; the `width` attribute overrides the default and the `width` style property overrides the attribute. So no matter what value you set the property to, you will never go back to the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JavaScript, you can copy the values of the `width` and `height` attributes to an inline style.

```js
var img = document.querySelector('.row .col img:not([srcset])');

img.style.width = img.getAttribute('width')+'px';
img.style.height = img.getAttribute('height')+'px';
```

```css
/* Untouchable CSS */
.row .col img:not([srcset]) {
    width: auto;
}

.row .col img {
    height: auto;
}
/*End Untouchable CSS */
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <a href="#"><img width="85" height="30" src="https://placehold.it/340x120/00aaaa/fff/?text=Logo"></a>   
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

After a lot of introspection, the real answer is that there is no CSS answer. This is not an issue of what CSS to use, but one of precedence.
The actual process of what value is used goes like this:

- Take the default value
- Is there an attribute value? If so, use it
- Is there any explicit CSS? If so, use that.

and this has nothing to do with CSS specificity. So even if the default value of `width` is `auto`, setting it to `auto` in the stylesheet does change the appearance.

The same, by the way, is true of other CSS properties that have attribute equivalents. As an example, take `text-align`. Its default value is `start`, which means either `left` or `right` depending on the circumstances. So if you have this code:

```html
<p align="center">This is some html</p>
```

even if the default value of `text-align` is `start`, it will still be centered, because of the attribute. However, if you set `text-align` ***explicitly*** in your stylesheet, the property will override the attribute and it will be left aligned after all.

```css
p {text-align:start}
```

```html
<p align="center">This is some html</p>
```

So at the end of the day, if you don't want a reset stylesheet to change your default appearance, the solution is to remove those styles from the reset stylesheet. You cannot reset the reset with new CSS!

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to this discussion as I discovered the problem.

Everything mentioned above is true. But what modern browsers are doing in HTML5 is no longer working as before as they changed how browsers are required to interpret `width` and `height` attributes. They are not required now to honor those HTML values to determine width and height but use them as "hints" to create an "aspect ratio" that determines the final dimensions in CSS. Those dimensions fall back to the image's native width and height if you alter the CSS. The browsers use both the attributes, your CSS, and the images native dimensions to determine height and width via a new CSS value it creates that overrides the original attribute values. So those values are now lost. Crazy!

For proof of this change in HTML5, try the following:

Create an image 100 x 100 pixels and add an "img" element to your web page. Now resize it to a custom value of 500 x 500 pixels by adding 500 to your image's width and height attributes as so:

```
<img id="image1" src="/image.jpg" width="500" height="500" onclick="Javascript: alert(this.width);"  />
```

Notice the Javascript popup alert I added. That will prove what happens to the images attribute values. Now create a style that "reverts" or resets the images styles in the browser:

```
    html body img {
        all: revert;
    }
```

WHAT IS THE WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF THE IMAGE? Click the image with the Javascript alert box event. The pop up says "100", the images native width not the attribute width. It's not 500 pixels as you set on the attribute any longer. Why?

What's happened is the new HTML5 standards have asked vendors to no longer honor the width and height attributes but "calculate" the new width and height based on an aspect ratio first and THEN create width and height in CSS in memory. When I used "all:revert" to reset the styles, I destroy that calculated value that overwrites the HTML attributes so even Javascript pulls the wrong value! But the browser erased the img attribute width and height. So its gone!

In other words, you CANNOT retrieve the ORIGINAL width and height attribute values as they have been interpreted. The browser in HTML5 has removed it and re-interpreted it to a CSS custom value. This is why I would trust the the old W3C rather than the new WHATSWG standards body as there is no standard any more. They say in their documentation:

**"The dimension attributes are not intended to be used to stretch the image".**

Images traditionally have been doing that for years. So this now breaks many website images. Its a changing set of rules that are not intuitive and not reflective of how users expect attributes to perform.

BTW...you can get around this "bug" buy adding "data-width" and "data-height" attributes to your images and then using Javascript to "re-apply" the true values again. But the modern browsers will still try and default to the image's actual width and height, not the attributes, if you alter their CSS interpretation.